# Serialise child collections in Python (with jsonpickle)

Tags: python, json, recursion, jsonpickle

I'd like to serialise a python list that contains nested lists. The code below constructs the object to be serialised from a gnome keyring but the [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/api.html#jsonpickle-high-level-api) encoder, doesn't serialise the child lists. With `unpicklable=True`, I simply get:

```
[{"py/object": "__main__.Collection", "label": ""}, {"py/object": "__main__.Collection", "label": "Login"}]
```

I've experimented with setting/not setting `max_depth` and tried lots of depth numbers, but regardless, the pickler will only pickle the top level items.

How do I make it serialise the entire object structure?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import secretstorage
import jsonpickle

class Secret(object):
    label = ""
    username = ""
    password = ""

    def __init__(self, secret):
        self.label = secret.get_label()
        self.password = '%s' % secret.get_secret()
        attributes = secret.get_attributes()
        if attributes and 'username_value' in attributes:
            self.username = '%s' % attributes['username_value']

class Collection(object):
    label = ""
    secrets = []

    def __init__(self, collection):
        self.label = collection.get_label()
        for secret in collection.get_all_items():
            self.secrets.append(Secret(secret))


def keyring_to_json():
    collections = []
    bus = secretstorage.dbus_init()
    for collection in secretstorage.get_all_collections(bus):
        collections.append(Collection(collection))

    pickle = jsonpickle.encode(collections, unpicklable=False);
    print(pickle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyring_to_json()
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, and was able to resolve it by moving the declaration of arrays inside of the init:

```
class Collection(object):
    label = ""
    # secrets = [] (move this into __init__)

   def __init__(self, collection):
        self.secrets = []
        self.label = collection.get_label()
        for secret in collection.get_all_items():
            self.secrets.append(Secret(secret))
```